# Scheduling Push Notifications via a Web UI

Tags: push-notification, scheduled-tasks, cron, celery

I'm digging into creating a simple web interface for scheduling iOS push notifications to occur either at a specific time or periodically in the future.

For example, someone could use this notification data:

```
"This is a periodic push notification!" - Every Monday - Expires Oct 31
"This will only happen once!" - Sept 20
```

and have the first one be executed every monday until october 31st and the second occur on september 20th.

I've done some research for some server software I could install to do this sort of thing, but I'm at a bit of a loss as to the recommended software to achieve this sort of thing.  Is there ready-made software that could be recommended for scheduling push notifications?

If not, I'm also curious about software that would allow me to schedule my own tasks from input in a web form.  Could I add/remove cron tasks through PHP? Or is it more appropriate to use something like [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) for this sort of thing? I guess since I haven't got much web development experience, I'm unsure of what the most appropriate approach and tools would be fore this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to make cron task for specific events, you have to call at a define (but high) frequency a program through cron. TMHO having a program updating CRON for the purpose you describe is a bad idea.

Then this specific program has to send notifications based on the business logic you want. I implement such programs in PHP usually, then I can call them through cli or wget (this case require a bit more of work to avoid security problems since an attacker can call it too).